# How to use portable ffmpeg in php

Tags: ffmpeg-php

I write a php script that create video in window OS from static images and audio through FFMPEG. But my concern is, in order to use that script FFMPEG must be installed in your window machine. Is it possible to use portable FFMPEG which is also platform independent.

Comment: i think it is not possible u must install it completely.

Comment: Why don't you just try it if you have a portable version at hand?